# How can you prompt for the EULA in Kickstart?

Tags: redhat, rhel6, kickstart

I am trying to modify a Kickstart script so that it **does not** auto-accept the EULA (which it seems to skip right now.)

Answer (score 1):

The parameter is:

```
eula Accepted
```

Comment: this failed for me with `Kickstart command eula does not take any arguments`

Answer (score 1):

The EULA presentation is a function of Firstboot, not Kickstart itself. [Firstboot runs if the requirements below are satisfied](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/ch-firstboot.html):

> Firstboot is only available on systems after a graphical installation or after a kickstart installation where a desktop and the X window system were installed and graphical login was enabled. If you performed a text-mode installation or a kickstart installation that did not include a desktop and the X window system, the firstboot configuration tool does not appear.

You might not be seeing Firstboot if your installation does not meet these requirements or if it has been explicity disabled with the [Kickstart option](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html); `firstboot --disable`.